# PHP PSR standard

Tags: php

Is this allowed to be written by PHP PSR standards?

It's a one line expression:

```
isset($item['name']) && $product->setName($item['name']);
```

If no, could you explain if it is a control structure or something else?
Link to PSR for reference:
http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#control-structures

**Updated:**
The question is about a way to write this statement according to PSR. As I can see PSR doesn't have any example for the code above and recommends to write it like:

```
if (isset($item['name'])) {
    $product->setName($item['name']);
}
```

So once again: What is the correct way to write it in a way to meet PSR or both ways are allowed?

Comment: Install [`phpcs`](https://packagist.org/packages/squizlabs/php_codesniffer) and try it.

Comment: I use PHPStorm with phpcs installed, I don't use any external configuration file for phpcs, but use PSR2 configuration provided by PHPStorm out of the box. IDE doesn't highlight this code but still - I'm not sure that it's correct.